# How to write a square of a trigonometric polynomial cosine?

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, trigonometric-series, multinomial-coefficients, sum-of-squares-method

How to write a square of a polynomial of the form
$$\left(1 + 2\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \cos k \theta\right)^2$$
with an explicit formula for just the coefficient of $$\cos k\theta$$  in terms of $k$ and the sequence $$a_1,\cdots , a_n$$ for some given $k$.

Answer (score 0):

Upon squaring, this becomes
$$4\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\cos(k\theta)\right)^2+4\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\cos(k\theta)+1$$
So let's look at the coefficient of $\cos(k\theta)$ from each specific term. We obviously can't get $\cos(k\theta)$ from the last term. The coefficient of $\cos(k\theta)$ in the second term is just $4a_k$. The first term is the tricky one. Let's forget about the $4$ for a moment:
$$(a_1\cos(1\theta)+a_2\cos(2\theta)+\cdots+a_n\cos(n\theta))(a_1\cos(1\theta)+a_2\cos(2\theta)+\cdots+a_n\cos(n\theta))$$
How do we get $\cos(k\theta)$? Well, if we choose some $a_j\cos(j\theta), a_t\cos(t\theta)$, they must multiply to $\cos(k\theta)$. Hence
$$\cos(j\theta)\cos(t\theta)=\cos(k\theta)$$
So the coefficient of $\cos(k\theta)$
$$4\left(\sum_{1\le j,t\le n, \cos(j\theta)\cos(t\theta)=\cos(k\theta)}a_ja_t\right)+4a_k$$
Can you simplify the sum?